# Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB版にインストールしたUbuntu 20.10でYouTubeなどを再生することができないです。ビデオメモリの増やしたいです。

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpu

**現象**
Ubuntu 20.10でYouTubeなど動画を再生できないです。

**期待値**
ビデオメモリを増やしてYouTubeなどを再生したいです。

**再現手順**

1. Ubuntu 20.10を、Raspberry Pi Desktop(旧:Raspbian)上のRaspberry Pi Imagerを使ってUSB SSDにインストールする。
2. Ubuntu 20.10をUSB SSDからRaspberry Pi 4Bを使って起動する。

Comment: こちらの方法が検索で引っかかりましたので参考までに。ブラウザからだと GPU あんまり使ってくれないっぽい？です。 [Raspberry Piシリーズの性能を活かす \(Raspberry Pi OS\)::kakurasanのLinux書庫](https://kakurasan.tk/raspberrypi/raspberrypi-improve-performance/#gpu%E3%82%92%E6%B4%BB%E3%81%8B%E3%81%99)

Comment: あとビデオメモリの増設はメモリの割当で変えられるようです。検索するとそれっぽい方法がたくさん出てきますよ